Difference between Array comparison in .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 7
In my .NET Framework 4.8 code this comparison returns false:
List<myObject> _myList = new List<myObject>();

_myList.ToArray() == _myList.ToArray() // false 

Now, I upgraged my code to .NET 7, and the same comparison returns true:
List<myObject> _myList = new List<myObject>();

_myList.ToArray() == _myList.ToArray() // true

Does that make any sense to anyone?
I expected the same result in both cases.

Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new project and reproduce this behaviour.

What are _myList and ToArray?

Comparing two arrays with == will do a reference compare ("are they the same object?"), not a value compare ("do they contain the same values?"). So maybe the implementation of ToArray() has changed

Can't reproduce. I get false (as expected) in all frameworks I've tried (4.8, 7 and 8). (I'm assuming _myList is a List<T> and ToArray() is the built in implementation)

No repro. If the list is List<int> _myList=[1,2,3]; then _myList.ToArray() == _myList.ToArray() is False

The .NET docs have links directly to the source code and the docs for List.ToArray show that a new array is always created UNLESS THE LIST IS EMPTY

Is the list empty perhaps? In that case the same cached empty instance is returned, as it should

.ToArray() on an ICollection should return a new array instance. If the lists are empty, the result is Array.Empty<T>(), which returns a singleton, but that's an undocumented implementation detail.

@JeremyLakeman I'm pretty sure it is documented in one of Stephen Toub's performance blog posts that explain how each .NET Core version reduced memory allocation

As a performance enhancement, sure. But as an equality test? I doubt that's defined behaviour.

Sorry, you are right. I will elaborate a bit on the question. However, I think I have found the answer.

@SalvadorNasser you haven't asked a question yet. Empty arrays are immutable so there's no reason to return a new array every time. What are you trying to do? There are probably different/better ways to do it

@JeremyLakeman this behavior is documented here - in a Github issue going all the way back to .NET Core 1. .NET Core is an open source project so the docs and actual design, specification and behavior aren't the same.

Yes that github issue is a discussion is about the exact change in runtime behaviour that this question is about. But I wouldn't call that documentation on the expected behaviour of .ToArray and the assumptions a developer should make about this function. There's a difference between "these are the documented rules that all C# implementations must follow" and "this is what happens with this edge case, on this specific runtime implementation". IMHO If you are writing code that breaks when .ToArray does or doesn't return a singleton, you are doing something wrong.

Totally agree. This question doesn't arise from production code; it's a curiosity that came up during a concept unit test, but it caught my attention so much that I felt curious about it.

OK, I think this only happens when it is an empty array. In .NET 7, it must now return Array.Empty, and that's why it is true.

.NET 7 is .NET Core 7 and such inefficiencies were fixed as far back as .NET Core 1. An empty array is immutable so there's no reason to return a new empty array each time. The question on the other hand didn't show what the array contained.

Why do you care about reference equality anyway? What are you trying to do? Are you trying to use the array as some kind of cache? Or use it with Interlocked.CompareExchange?

While Array.Empty will return the same array each time it is called, this is an undocumented implementation detail, which your code shouldn't rely on.

It actually is, all the way back to a .NET Core 1.0 preview. In that sense, empty lists in .NET Core "always" returned Array.Empty. I don't see how the use of Array.Empty could break any application code, but that's not something that will change arbitrarily in a future version. It will be explicitly designed through GH issues, announced in previews and blog posts before it's finalized.
